# Ubuntu 14.04 don't start

Tags: 14.04, startup, logo

I'm new with Ubuntu. At start, I don't get to the login screen. What should I do?
I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed. I have 3.16.0-49-generic.
With command line by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, it works but I don't have network.
It seems that i have problem with my package depot but I am unable to update nor reinstall because network is not running.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu . By "my pc still at ubuntu logo" do you mean you don't get to the login screen?

Comment: Hi, yes i don't get to the login screen

Answer (score 0):

I've solved by:
1- Re-configure internet connection with:
sudo ip link set dev eth0 down
sudo dhclient eth0

2- update:
sudo apt-get update

3- reinstall unity:
sudo apt-get install unity

4- reboot